# Getting ERROR 010161 in geopackage using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, geopackage, extract-by-mask

I am using ArcMap 10.7.1.

I'm trying to share a model via geopackage. The model works fine while open in my .mxd file and shares without any errors but when I open the newly saved geopackage I receive error 010161 once it gets to the reclassify tool. I can't figure out why it only fails here. Seems to be an issue with the pathway but I don't understand why the previous tools work if that is the case.

Also, the geopackage should have bundled all the data so file navigation should only come from the scratch workspace?

Also the same happens for each of the reclassify steps.

[image: Geoprocessing Results]

[image: model]

Comment: What does this have to do with GeoPackage? It seems that you are using .gdb.

Comment: The model works fine before I open it as a geopackage. So I'm not sure if the packaging is a potential source of error.

Comment: When you say GeoPackage did you talk about the open, standards-based container (file ending in .gpkg) ? In your screenshot there are only reference to ESRI file géodatabase (.gdb). If you are indeed using a .gpkg did you try to share your data and model using an ESRI specific format ? (In my experience ESRI product work very well when using ESRI format, a little less well when using open format...). Also what the point of using a .gpkg to share a model that can only be used with ESRI product

Comment: Are you opening "session_6.gdb"? That's a geodatabase, not geopackage (.gpkg).

Comment: I've opened a .gpkg in ArcMap called Model (that I created - I'm trying to verify it works before sharing it). I'm not opening Session_6.gdb. That was the source gdb for the layers used when I initially created the model. I don't think the model should be navigating to this gdb when trying to run the packaged model.